# MVC5 CRUD best methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have been given a project where CRUD is key. List of stuff on a web page, add to it, delete it, update, the usual. However they want it on a single page for the end user.

I am using C# for the back-end connections to the database and ajax to handle the CRUD functions.

I have built two different web applications over the weekend and today. One using partial pages (create and update) loaded into jQuery UI dialogs (which I don't like as it causes all sorts of issues with other jQuery libraries).

The other is with Knockout.js which I have some concerns about as I didn't write it out from scratch (I am trying to improve my JS as I feel this is the key route for dynamic CRUD) and paging on the frontend doesn't seem to be easily customisable.

What are/is the best way/s of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single Page Applicacion is what you are looking for, here is a tutorial http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/build-a-single-page-application-spa-with-aspnet-web-api-and-angularjs.

There are a number of libraries you can use to accomplish this, including angular, knockout, but personally I like to have full control of all interactions so I almost always go ajax and partial views.

The issues with other libraries could be because the dynamic elements coming and going, maybe a lot of those could be fix using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event handler function. but it's just a guess it could be something more complex.

Comment: Thanks for your response - was just looking at Angular, but was concerned it would give me the same control as EF or Knockout, both do what I want end product-wise but like you said, control and understanding is what I'm looking for. So with Angular this makes use of AJAX and partial views?